# What are the differences between getNodeHandle() and getPrivateNodeHandle() in nodelet?

Tags: nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found some examples of nodelets used both getNodeHandle() and getPrivateNodeHandle () to get the ros::NodeHandle， and I felt that they had the same effects. So what are the exact deferences between getNodeHandle() and getPrivateNodeHandle () in nodelet?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32061/what-are-the-differences-between-getnodehandle()-and-getprivatenodehandle()-in-nodelet?/) by [monsterkappa](https://answers.ros.org/users/1863/monsterkappa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2012-04-17

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Private node handles are used for accessing resources (advertising, subscribing topics, parameters, ...) in the nodelet's private namespace. The non-private version should give a node handle in the manager's namespace.

Example: you run a nodelet foo in the manager named bar. When advertising the topic baz using the private node handle, the topic should be something like that:

/bar/foo/baz

When using the non-private node handle, you should get:

/bar/baz

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nihalsoans91](https://answers.ros.org/users/37719/nihalsoans91/) on 2020-05-11**:
Thank you, Explains the question I had.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As a general rule (there are exceptions), you should access parameters using `getPrivateNodeHandle()`, and topics via `getNodeHandle()`.

That is because parameters are (generally) private to your nodelet, while topics will be shared with other nodes and nodelets.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 20

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [emacsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3662/emacsd/) on 2014-07-08**:
I wish I can vote for this answer 1000 times!